# Saving data into bootable pendrive

Tags: boot, live-usb

I've created a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu 13.04, and my windows and linux machines still recognize it as a normal FAT32 flash drive with data in it. Would it still work the linux boot if I saved more data in it as long as I don't delete anything that the USB boot installer put there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could still function as a normal usb drive (be it a bootable one).
I would recommend putting your extra files in a directory but that's optional.
Please do keep in mind that if you've enabled your bootable usb to save changes to the usb that you should keep about 50 to 100 mb of space free from data.